# Hijack site url on sub domain for translation

Tags: multi-language, site-url

Ok, i have complicated issuse (i think)... i created a site that has 3 languages
without any plugin since none meet my needs....

**i create 2 sub domains named:**

- he.example.com
- en.example.com

they both lead to the same site.

**When the he.example.com loads:**
i want to change all the links inside the page according
to the **specific** sub-domain... for example my menus, recent posts
and all the other link on pages.

**Reason:**
that way i can control which meta boxes, texts and stuff are being loaded
on the site and thus creating a translated sites without needing any plugin
(tested 3 so far - none of them answer my requirments)...

**question:**
how can i "hijack" the site url the page uses when loads and change the
output accoring to the current sub-domain?

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134088/3094)

Comment: Wow, looks intersting ;) thanks for the share - going to read more in the following link to see if this answers my question.