# How do I keep multiple domain for my wordpress site

Tags: permalinks

I want category ID 1,2,3,4,5 to be

```
DomainB.com
```

category ID 6,7,8,9,10

```
DomainC.com
```

and homepage to be

```
DomainA.com
```

I thought of using 302 redirect or edit htaccess, but what is the best way to achieve this with wordpress.

I also thought of editing the function permalink, but it won't solve the homepage, and category page issue.

Comment: [This may help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134088/3094)

Comment: @Sisir, it doesn't achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Beside making certain categories to some domain. Why don't you create some post type like post-type-domainb and then redirect

```
domain.com/post-type-domainb to 
domanb.com
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work.